# Jquery clone( ) function not working with toggleClass( ). Trying to clone image yet image moves from current location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

When a user clicks an image I would like it to clone as a fixed and more larger image but when I try to use the toggleClass() function, the image moves from it's previous location which I do not want. I want to be able to click an image and get a bigger view and be able to toggle it back while only limiting one image at a time

```js
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img_box").click(function(){
        if(count<2){
        $(this).clone().attr({ 'class': 'img_box' + count }).appendTo(".zoom");
        $(this).toggleClass("zoom");
        count++;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.img_container {
    justify-content: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 5px;
    list-style: none;
}
.img_box {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.img_box1 {
}
.zoom {
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 55%;
    height: 85%;
    left: -50%;
    right: -50%;
    top: 9%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='img_container'>
<li><img class='img_box' src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0llDSWL9Xm0/Ta0fJ3ulMDI/AAAAAAAAAAk/G5O-DfxD3PI/s1600/7.jpg' ></li>
</div>

<div class='img_container'>
<li><img class='img_box' src='https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/1200x675/p049tgdb.jpg' ></li>
</div>

<div class='img_container'>
<li><img class='img_box' src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uctFXnJjKvc/UCF-SlHorHI/AAAAAAAAAIU/Y4vtiVI1Jjk/s1600/animal+(5).jpg' ></li>
</div>

<div class='img_container'>
<li><img class='img_box' src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-g913BsBiiq4/UAFN4Z2XQBI/AAAAAAAADtc/EdyJQODnHBw/s1600/baby-animal-wallpapers-1.jpg' ></li>
</div>
```

Comment: @fenghengzhi's answer should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I was also thinking about `.insertAfter(this)` idea. Added a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/phvsfw3g/11/) guessing the functionality expected. Can give it a look.

I removed the zoomed image if the count is larger and decremented the count again so that a new image can be clicked and zoomed.

```
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img_box").click(function(){
        if(count>1)
        {
        $('.img_box1').remove();
        count--;
        }
        $(this).clone().attr({ 'class': 'img_box' + count+' zoom' }).insertAfter(this);
        //$(this).toggleClass("zoom");
        count++;
        $(".img_box1").click(function(){
            $('.img_box1').remove();
            count--;       
            });
    });

});
```

Comment: Didn't touch your css though. In this functionality you wont need your zoom class to be honest. You can put the zoom code in your `img_box1` class and it should work.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't see your other comment and thought your code wasn't working lol but yea my zoom class was no good

Answer (score 1):

It should work.

```js
var zoom = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img_box").click(function(){
        if(!zoom){
        $(this).clone().attr({ 'class': 'img_box zoom' }).insertAfter(this).click(function(){$(this).remove();zoom=false;});
        //$(this).toggleClass("zoom");
        //count++;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it  like this: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/PBpjVP

**JS**

```
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img_box").click(function(){
        if(count<2){
        $(this).clone().attr({ 'class': 'img_box' + count }).appendTo(".zoom");
        count++;
        }                                       $(this).toggleClass("zoom");
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.img_container {
    justify-content: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 5px;
    list-style: none;
}
.img_box {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.img_box1 {
}
.zoom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```